# How to mock downstream API call using mockito

Tags: unit-testing, rust, actix-web

I'm attempting to use the mockito crate to mock downstream API calls. However, it doesn't seem to be functioning as anticipated. Here is my code,

```
use actix_web::{get, App, HttpServer, Responder };
use reqwest::Client;

async fn get_downstream_data() -> Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error> {
    let client = Client::builder().build();
    let api_url = "https://reqres.in/api/users/2";
    let response = client.expect("REASON").get(api_url).send().await;
    response
}

#[get("/hello")]
async fn index() -> impl Responder {
    let response = get_downstream_data().await;
    if response.is_ok() {
        println!("{:?}", response.unwrap());
    }
    "Hello, World!"
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    HttpServer::new(|| App::new().service(index))
        .bind(("127.0.0.1", 8080))?
        .run().await
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[actix_web::test]
    async fn test_api() {
        let mut server = mockito::Server::new();
        let host = server.host_with_port();
        let url = server.url();
        let mock = server
            .mock("GET", "/api/users/2")
            .with_status(200)
            .with_header("content-type", "")
            .with_header("x-api-key", "1234")
            .with_body("world")
            .create();
        let res = get_downstream_data().await;
        println!("{:?}", res);
        mock.assert();
    }
}
```

in the above code, how to test the `get_downstream_data` method without calling the actual API `https://reqres.in/api/users/2`

Comment: You shouldn't be testing `reqwest` that's for `reqwests` tests to do.

Comment: You need to be able to inject the base URL of the API if you want to test the function without hitting the actual endpoint. As written, the code will always hit the actual endpoint.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Could you please help me how to inject base URL

Comment: @Gurunath You could just accept the base URL as a parameter to the function. Or you could retrieve it from some kind of configuration mechanism. Or you could make the function part of a class that initializes a default base URL and has a function to set a different base URL. Or you could use a compile-time environment variable. There's basically an infinite number of options, and what's best for you depends on the specifics of your project.